# Can the Clarity Kitchen-Sink App be published

Tags: vmware-clarity

Having the source code for the Kitchen Sink app would be beneficial. https://github.com/vmware/clarity/wiki/Kitchen-Sink-App. http://clarity-ks.surge.sh/

Any chance this could be published?

Comment: Its already open sourced: https://github.com/vmware/clarity/tree/master/src/ks-app